# Design Custom Box Class To Be Displayed In Applet

Tags: java, applet

```
import java.awt.Color;

import java.awt.Graphics;



public class Box {

    public static int length;

    private int upperLeftX;
    private int upperLeftY;
    private int height;
    private int width;

    private Color boxColor;


    public Box(int upperX, int upperY, int h, int w, Color myColor) {

        this.upperLeftX = upperX;
        this.upperLeftY = upperY;
        this.height = h;

        this.width = w;
        this.boxColor = myColor;




        this. setBoxColor(Color.BLUE);
          this. setBoxColor(Color.CYAN);
          this. setBoxColor(Color.BLACK);

          this. setBoxColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);

          this. setBoxColor(Color.GRAY);
           this.setBoxColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
           this.setBoxColor(Color.MAGENTA);

           this.setBoxColor(Color.ORANGE);
           this.setBoxColor(Color.PINK);
           this.setBoxColor(Color.RED);

           this.setBoxColor(Color.WHITE);
           this.setBoxColor(Color.YELLOW);
           this.setBoxColor(Color.BLACK);

           this.setBoxColor(Color.GREEN);

           this.setBoxColor(Color.PINK);
    }

    public Box() {

    }



    public int getUpperLeftX() {


        return upperLeftX;

    }





    public void setUpperLeftX(int upperLeftX) {





        this.upperLeftX = upperLeftX;





    }








    public int getUpperLeftY() {

        return upperLeftY;
    }




    public void setUpperLeftY(int upperLeftY) {

        this.upperLeftY = upperLeftY;

    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;


    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(int width) {


        this.width = width;
    }

    public Color getBoxColor() {
        return boxColor;
    }


    public void setBoxColor(Color boxColor) {
        this.boxColor = boxColor;
    }

    public void display(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(boxColor);
        g.fillRect(upperLeftX, upperLeftY, width, height);

    }
}

import java.awt.*;

import java.applet.Applet;

import java.awt.Button;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class Grid extends Applet implements ActionListener{


        public Button changeButton;
        public Button changeColorButton;

        public void init() {

            resize(400, 500);


            setBackground(Color.white);


            changeButton = new Button("Change");

            add(changeButton);


            changeButton.addActionListener(this); {



            }

            add(changeButton);


        }

            public void paint(Graphics g){
        changeButton.setLocation(150, 450);

        Box greenBox = new Box(0, 0, 100, 100, Color.GREEN);
        greenBox.display(g);

        Box blueBox = new Box(0, 100, 100, 100, Color.BLUE);
        blueBox.display(g);


        Box cyanBox = new Box(0, 200, 100, 100, Color.CYAN);
        cyanBox.display(g);


        Box blackBox = new Box(0, 300, 100, 100, Color.BLACK);
        blackBox.display(g);


        Box darkGrayBox = new Box(100, 0, 100, 100, Color.DARK_GRAY);
        darkGrayBox.display(g);



        Box grayBox = new Box(100, 100, 100, 100, Color.GRAY);
        grayBox.display(g);


        Box lightGrayBox = new Box(100, 200, 100, 100, Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        lightGrayBox.display(g);





        Box magentaBox = new Box(100, 300, 100, 100, Color.MAGENTA);
        magentaBox.display(g);

        Box orangeBox = new Box(200, 0, 100, 100, Color.ORANGE);
        orangeBox.display(g);

        Box pingBox = new Box(200, 100, 100, 100, Color.PINK);
        pingBox.display(g);

        Box redBox = new Box(200, 200, 100, 100, Color.RED);
        redBox.display(g);

        Box whiteBox = new Box(200, 300, 100, 100, Color.WHITE);
        whiteBox.display(g);

        Box yellowBox = new Box(300, 0, 100, 100, Color.YELLOW);
        yellowBox.display(g);

        Box blackBox1 = new Box(300, 100, 100, 100, Color.BLACK);
        blackBox1.display(g);

        Box greenBox1 = new Box(300, 200, 100, 100, Color.GREEN);
        greenBox1.display(g);

        Box pingBox1 = new Box(300, 300, 100, 100, Color.PINK);
        pingBox1.display(g);

    }

    public String getChangeColorButton() {
        return getChangeColorButton();

    }

    public void setChangeColorButton(Button changeColorButton) {
        this.changeColorButton = changeColorButton;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }

}
```

Comment: I been trying to get the applet to display 16 colors on a 4x4 boxes, and now I add a change button to change the colors but it does not change, this where my instructions.

Comment: Let's revisit the java1_BoxProject you did for an earlier lesson (it should still be in your Java1_Homework working set). 

Edit the Grid.java applet to add a button component. When we click the button it should change the colors of the 16 Box objects on the Applet. 

When you're done, hand in the java1_BoxProject project.

Comment: Could you please state what you are looking for in the question itself.

Comment: I want to know why there is no action on the button? why I call most methods and the button does not shows any action

Comment: i been trying a different ways to get the applet with the button work so it can show it all the colors at random on a 4x4 box grid,I'm just confused, I'm a beginner in java, but still trying.

Comment: @Twister would you be able to help me, what am I doing wrong I call all the methods but still now it just shows one color before it shows allot but the button no action.